# Accessing assigned variable name inside callback function - Node.js/ Express

Tags: node.js, express, callback, this, pass-by-reference

Using Node.js and Express:

When I call the Application.listen method, I can access the returned Server object by name inside the callback function I pass as an argument to the Application.listen method.

```
var myVariableName = app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(myVariableName.address().port)
});
```

I can already call methods on `myVariableName` even though I'm in the act of creating/assigning to that variable!

How is this possible? I want to understand so I can implement functions that allow me to reference returned object by name in a callback argument.

Comment: *even though I'm in the act of creating/assigning to that variable!* At the time the callback runs, the variable has finished getting assigned to.

Answer (score 0):

As specified in comment by [certainperformance](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9515207/certainperformance), you can not get that variable. Instead you can use another event as,

```
app.listen(3000)
app.on('listening', () =>{
  console.log(app.address().port)
})
```